# AWS Lambda to list S3 buckets with listBuckets() has no effect

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am new to writing Lambda in JS. I want to be able to list the S3 buckets I have, however, below lambda doesn't return what I expect, ie. list of buckets.
What have I done wrong? The only thing I am aware of is the line "console.log('hihi')" didn't print in my Cloudwatch log, so something going on when listBuckets() is invoked but I can't see any relevant logs... Tks in advance for any help !!

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'});

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    // Create S3 service object
    var s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'});
    var params = {};
    // Call S3 to list the buckets
    s3.listBuckets(params, function(err, data) {
      console.log('hihi')
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error", err);
      } else {
        console.log("Success", data.Buckets);
      }
    });
    
    // TODO implement
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
    };
    return response;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `async` handler. Therefore, to your lambda does return before `listBucket` has a chance to execute. One way to overcome is through a `Promise` as shown in [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html#nodejs-handler-async).

Therefore, you could modify your code as follows:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'});

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    
    const promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        
      // Create S3 service object
      var s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'});
      var params = {};
      // Call S3 to list the buckets
      s3.listBuckets(params, function(err, data) {
        console.log('hihi')
        if (err) {
          console.log("Error", err);
        } else {
          console.log("Success", data.Buckets);
        }
      });

    })
    return promise
};
```